# How can I create a view from already populated table in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Good day,
I am still pretty new at this and any advice will be highly appreciated.

I have created a database with players for a sports team. Now I want to use the displayed table to create a view for the players that will be selected with the team to show the team sheet.

I cannot find a way to get this to work. I want to add a submit button or something like it so that all the players that are checked be populated into a view and displayed afterwards to be printed.
Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Table displayed:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Surname</th>
        <th>School</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Age Group</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
        <th>Add to Team</th>

        <form action="" method="post">
    </tr>
</thead>
<!-- Table body -->
<tbody>
    <?php foreach($result as $index => $row) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['Name']; ?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['Surname']; ?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['School']; ?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['Age']; ?></td>
        <td align="left"><?php echo $row['age_group']; ?></td>
        <td><a href="edit_player.php" title="Edit" onclick="return confirm('Confirm Player Delete ?')"></span> Edit</td>
        <td><a href="" title="Delete" onclick="return confirm('Confirm Player Delete ?')"></span> Delete</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="add_to_team"/>Add to Team </span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Table structrue for players:

```
+---------------------------------------+
|   `Name` text NOT NULL,               |
|   `Surname` text NOT NULL,            |
|   `Id_num` varchar(13) NOT NULL,      |
|   `School` text NOT NULL,             |
|   `Age` varchar(2) NOT NULL,          |
|   `Address` varchar(200) NOT NULL,    |
|   `Address2` varchar(20) NOT NULL,    |
|   `City` varchar(20) NOT NULL,        |
|   `Postal_code` varchar(4) NOT NULL,  |
|   `player_pic` longblob NOT NULL,     |
|   `birth_cert` longblob NOT NULL,     |
|   `Club` varchar(30) NOT NULL,        |
|   `age_group` varchar(8) NOT NULL,    |
|   `DOB` varchar(11) NOT NULL,         |
|   `posistion` varchar(30) NOT NULL,   |
|   `contact` varchar(10) NOT NULL,     |
|   `f_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,      |
|   `f_phone` varchar(30) NOT NULL,     |
|   `f_email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,     |
|   `m_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,      |
|   `m_phone` varchar(30) NOT NULL,     |
|   `m_email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,     |
|   `medical_aid` varchar(30) NOT NULL, |
|   `med_num` varchar(15) NOT NULL,     |
|   `med_card` blob NOT NULL,           |
|   `ice_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,    |
|   `ice_surname` varchar(20) NOT NULL, |
|   `ice_number` varchar(20) NOT NULL,  |
|   `jersey_size` varchar(5) NOT NULL,  |
|   `short_size` varchar(5) NOT NULL,   |
|   `golf_shirt` varchar(5) NOT NULL    |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Table structre for Teams:

```
+-------------------------------------+
| `Club` varchar(20) NOT NULL,        |
|   `Name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,      |
|   `Surname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,   |
|   `Posisiton` varchar(20) NOT NULL, |
|   `Picture` blob NOT NULL,          |
|   `Team` varchar(5) NOT NULL,       |
|   `date` date NOT NULL,             |
|   `Id_num` varchar(13) NOT NULL     |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: What is the table structure for teams, players, and players on teams? Also, by *view*, do you mean a mySQL view, or simply an HTML page to "view" the teams?

Comment: I have a table for the Players, Then a table with the teams that consists of the Club Name, Team Name, Player Name, Surname, Position, Age and photo. mySQL view would be better to keep a history but a HTML page to view on would also work.

Comment: A SQL view isn't "populated" and doesn't maintain a "history". It is simply a pre-written SELECT statement. When you select from a view, the data comes from the tables specified in the view at the time you do the select. If you provide the structure and relationship between the tables, a select with a join will be easy to construct.

Comment: Ok thanks that makes sense. Not sure how to get the correct format for the structure out of phpMyAdmin. As soon as I figure it out I will post the structre.

Comment: @SloanThrasher I added the structre above.

Comment: How are Teams and Players related? IOW, which field in Players indicates which Team they are on? And which field in Teams does that field match (Id_num)? Please don't let it be 'Club'. It should be an unsigned int field, probably an auto-incrementing field in Teams.

Comment: Hi Cindi, I'd suggest to read more books about Php and what is called templating so you will understand how to separate HTML from Php, and make all your code more easy to read and to maintain. A bit more work, but priceless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `Id_num` columns in your `Players` and `Teams` tables are unique identifiers. That's a guess because ordinarily such unique identifiers are defined as integers something like this to guarantee they are unique.

```
    ...
    Id_Num INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (Id_Num),
    ...
```

At any rate, if you're setting up relationships between players and teams, you have two choices.

**First choice:** if a player can only be on one team:

This is known in our trade as a **one-to-many relationship**. One Team, many Players.

Add a column to the `Players` table called Team_Id_Num. When you assign a player to a team, UPDATE the player's row and put the team's Id_Num value into that column for the player.

Then to get all the players on a team use a `JOIN` query like this:

```
   SELECT Teams.Name, Teams.Club, Players.Surname, Players.Name
     FROM Teams
     JOIN Players ON Players.Team_Id_Num = Teams.Id_Num
    WHERE Teams.Club = 'Manchester United'
```

Finally, if you really want an SQL VIEW for this you can do something like this

```
  CREATE VIEW Roster AS
       SELECT Teams.Name TeamName, Teams.Club, Players.Surname, Players.Name
         FROM Teams
         JOIN Players ON Players.Team_Id_Num = Teams.Id_Num
```

then query it by saying

```
      SELECT * FROM Roster WHERE Club = 'Arsenal'
```

**Second choice:** if a player can be on more than one team.

This is known in our trade as a **many-to-many relationship**. Many Teams, many Players.

Add a new table, containing two columns, called `Players_Teams`. This table defines the relationships between players and teams. These are the columns.  It's sometimes called a join table.

```
 Players_Id_Num
 Teams_Id_Num
```

When you assign a player to a team, INSERT a row into this table containing the Id_Num values for the player and the team in question.

If the team later sacks the player, DELETE the corresponding row.

Then to get all the players on a team use a `JOIN` query like this:

```
   SELECT Teams.Name, Teams.Club, Players.Surname, Players.Name
     FROM Teams
     JOIN Players_Teams ON Teams.Id_Num = Players_Teams.Teams_Id_Num
     JOIN Players ON Players_Teams.Player_Id_Num = Player.Id_Num
    WHERE Teams.Club = 'Manchester United'
```

Finally, if you really want an SQL view, you can create it like this

```
   CREATE VIEW Roster AS
        SELECT Teams.Name TeamName, Teams.Club, Players.Surname, Players.Name
          FROM Teams
          JOIN Players_Teams ON Teams.Id_Num = Players_Teams.Teams_Id_Num
          JOIN Players ON Players_Teams.Player_Id_Num = Player.Id_Num
```

and query it the same way as I showed earlier.